# Change SVN message editor

Tags: svn

So my co-worker felt it necessary to go onto my development box and do some code changes, then submit his work to subversion.  I never set the commit message editor, and all of a sudden, one day I forgot to add the `-m` handle and apparently he set the default editor to `emacs`.

Being that I don't know the first thing about `emacs` and prefer `vim` myself, how do I go about changing the default editor for SVN commands to `vim` after it's already been set?  I deleted the `.subversion` directory under the home directory, and it still prompts me.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Update your `SVN_EDITOR` environment variable.  You can try

```
echo $SVN_EDITOR
```

to see if this is set to something else in your shell - in which case you might want to take a look at your `.bashrc` (or similar) file.

Comment: Thanks!  Turns out it was being set in the .bash_profile file.

Answer (score 43):

You can add corresponding setting in your `$HOME/.subversion/config` or `%USERPROFILE%\Subversion\config`. e.g. for my Windows VM I have got:

```
[helpers]
editor-cmd = c:/emacs-24.3/bin/runemacs.exe
```

Answer (score 24):

The editor to be used by SVN can be set at the Subversion config, as [vvlevchenko suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15676280/906658). Edit the corresponding setting in your `%USERPROFILE%\Subversion\config` on Windows respectively `~/.subversion/config` on BSD, Linux, Mac OS.

To use Emacs with SVN on Windows:

```
[helpers]
editor-cmd = c:/emacs-24.3/bin/runemacs.exe
```

To use Nano with SVN on BSD, Linux or Mac OS:

```
[helpers]
editor-cmd = nano
```

Answer (score 15):

I also found this [here](http://www.techchorus.net/how-set-svneditor-environment-variable-vim) (but changed from vim to gedit):

Command:

`export SVN_EDITOR=gedit`

To permanently set this environment variable, put the below line in your ~/.bash_profile file:

```
sudo gedit ~/.bash_profile
export SVN_EDITOR=gedit
```

(save file)

Comment: Why would you need sudo?

Comment: If gedit is already open, a new tab opens, but the commit message is empty. You have to start gedit in standalone mode with the flag s: `export SVN_EDITOR="gedit -s"`

Comment: The url is getting 404, maybe the post is being removed?

Comment: @ad3luc You don't need to view that person's original post since I already wrote the relevant parts in my answer. (If it helped you, you could upvote it.) If you still *did* want to see the original post, you could use archive.org: https://web.archive.org/web/20100611212614/http://techchorus.net/how-set-svneditor-environment-variable-vim

Answer (score 3):

vim ~/.bashrc

```
export SVN_EDITOR=vim
```

source ~/.bashrc

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu, default editor for Subversion commit messages can be also changed by selecting default general command line text editor as described here: https://askubuntu.com/a/615181

```
sudo update-alternatives --config editor

  Selection    Path                Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /bin/nano            40        auto mode
  1            /bin/ed             -100       manual mode
  2            /bin/nano            40        manual mode
  3            /usr/bin/vim.basic   30        manual mode
  4            /usr/bin/vim.tiny    10        manual mode
```